# How to measure Java code unit test coverage per developer?

Tags: java, maven, junit, code-coverage, sonarqube

Scenario: a team works on a Java/Maven/JUnit project using some kind of SCM. We would like to increase test coverage, meaning all developers should test code more intensively. Measuring overall test coverage improvements using something like SonarQube is easy enough, but you need to do it per developer in order to be able to recognise the outliers: engineers which have the best test coverage and engineers whose coverage is worst.

How would you answer the question "what is the test coverage of code modified by developer X during the last month?" Is there a surrogate, approximate measure that could be followed more easily?

Comment: In theory it should be possible, you can use the `blame` function of your SCM to determine which lines were modified by which developer and compare it with the line-by-line coverage report. But is it a good idea? Unless your group is large, I don't think it is. It shows a lack of trust and while some maybe betray that trust, it'll be your best developers who will feel offended. A better proxy could be to analyse actual bugs, check if they originated from uncovered code and if so, who was the culprit. And if it happens to the same people all the time, have a quiet word with them.

Comment: In my opinion, if you need something like this you already have a huge problem with your work culture. What you want is a team which feels a such and takes full responsibility for the project together. What you want to do promotes a culture of blaming.

Comment: @AndréStannek Good point, rather than concentrating on who did it, it's always better to encourage people to write unit tests for code that isn't even "theirs".

Comment: @biziclop Your `isn't even "theirs"` leads me to a little addition: Read about collective code ownership/shared code :-)

Comment: @AndréStannek I know, that's why I used quote marks. But the point is: if people write unit tests for code they're not modifying, not only will your coverage be much better, they'll know exactly who the non-testers are amongst them.

Comment: @biziclop I noticed your quotes, the reading suggesting was intended for OP ;-)

Comment: While im not in favor of shaming/blaming as a means of motivation, we here use JaCoCo and ELCEmma + minimum code coverage percentages on our nightly builds to enforce unit test coverage. Its a bit of a pain, and deciding what the appropriate level of code coverage should be isn't an easy task, but it has helped uncover bugs, and promote unit testing in general. We also added a bit of fun to it by using the CI game: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin Makes things interesting at the very least.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this kind of reaction. First of all, I clearly stated the reasons for what I ask: this is not to punish anyone, but to understand why we are failing to deliver software with good test coverage. I consider this a very good reason to want to know how each developer is doing with testing. Second, if this was such an outrageous thing to measure, people wouldn't have bothered with implementing things like "svn blame" or the Developer Cockpit, as mentioned by Mithfindel bellow. I would therefore kindly ask everyone to focus on the question, instead of the reasons behind it.

Comment: `svn blame` is just an alias for `annotate` (which also has aliases `praise` and `ann`). It is rather tongue-in-cheek and the mere fact of its existence shouldn't be taken as an argument that assigning blame promotes a positive culture that contributes to code quality (as it usually doesn't).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am well aware of the fact that it is an alias: sadly, you completely missed my point. My point was that it is vital to know who did what, not to punish anyone, but to improve the quality of delivered SW. Apparently, many people here equate establishment of responsibility with punishment ("the beatings will continue until morale improves..."). There is NO punishment. If you want to e.g. educate or tutor the people lagging behind or reward the ones that do an outstanding job, this kind of accountability is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a commercial Developer Cockpit plugin that does just this, plus other nifty features.

Comment: Thanks Mithfindel: the Developer Cockpit seems to do exactly what I need. Nevertheless, it is rather pricey at 7k Euro per instance per year, so I will give it time before I accept an answer: I hope and expect there are other practical ways to go about it, even if they aren't so elegant.